# Troubleshooting Desktop That Can't Connect to Internet through Any Adapater, Even on Different OSes

Tags: networking, router, troubleshooting, network-adapter

I have a Windows 7 machine that also has Ubuntu on it. Yesterday the NIC spontaneously crapped out. I went and got a Dynex PCI NIC and set it up, my computer now finds networks but lists them as "unidentified" with either "no internet access" or "no network access".

I can't seem to detect other computers on the network either, so I do not believe it is even properly connecting to the LAN.

Things I have tried:

- Reinstalling/Updating NIC drivers.
- Restarting Router
- Restarting Modem
- Hooking desktop directly up to the modem's output (no router in
  between)
- ipconfig /flushdns
- netsh winsock reset
- ipconfig /release (gets an error, doesn't complete) ipconfig /renew
  (gets an error, doesn't complete)
- Trying to connect on Ubuntu (NIC is detected succesfully, but no
  connection is made)
- Running the computer on an entirely different network (same ISP
  though, but one is a business connection and one is a personal/home
  connection)
- setting up ipv4 info manually with static ip
- connecting via WiFi adapter
- connecting via Android phone w/ internet passthrough feature (detected as a network adapter, drivers installed, network found, exact same issues as with the NIC and the usb adapter)
- WiFi on different networks

The only thing I can think of at this point is maybe a service running on the computer that is causing issues. However, I did a restore to 2 days before the issue began, and the problem is the exact same, not to mention it won't connect on ubuntu either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cable problem? Have you tried if any other computer can use the same cable to get online?

Comment: Yes and, like I wrote, I have tried it on WiFi as well. I did verify that the cable provides network connectivity / internet to other computers.

Comment: @JonathonG so other computers *can* connect with the same adapters to the same network through the same router and modem; in other words, you have narrowed it down to that one specific system's *hardware*?

Comment: The Ubuntu that you tried is an already installed copy right? Try using a boot-disc OS like Knoppix, Bart's PE or other live CD (ie, pure, uncorrupted, unspecialized, uncustomized OS). If that works, then it is software (try—at least a temporary—a repair-install). If not, then it is the hardware; specifically the motherboard since you've tried different NICs and adapters.

Comment: Yes I've pretty much narrowed it down to the hardware, but I didn't know it was possible that the motherboard itself could somehow be preventing the connection, since both USB and PCI adapters have been tried with the same results.